# Multiplying Complex Numbers by i

Tags: vector-spaces, complex-numbers

[image]

But I am wondering why isit $PQ \perp QR$ and not $QP \perp QR$ as shown below?

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

How do I get the equation: $(i-1)b=ic-a=i(1-2i)-(-1+4i)=3-3i$?

Where does $(i-1)$ come from? I dont really get what they did after that either :(

Comment: The vectors $\vec{QP}$ and $\vec{PQ}$ are negatives of each other, i.e. pointing at opposite directions. If one is perpendicular to a known vector, so is the other.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, ic. so if I do $q-p=i(r-q)$ I am OK? Also, do they mean $|PQ|=|QR|$? Cos $PQ=QR$ seems wrong as they are different vectors?

Comment: No. It's still $p-q=i(r-q)$. Orientation matters, but your source relies on a picture alone to convey that. Multiplication by $i$ amounts to a **counterclockwise** rotation by 90 degrees.

Comment: OK, I updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is thinking of $p-q$ as the vector from $Q$ to $P$ and  $r-q$ as the vector from $Q$ to $R$.

As Jyrki notes, the author  is saying: by looking at the picture, 
that   $p-q=i(r-q)$ (because multiplication of $r-q$ by $i$ rotates it ccw by $90^\circ$).

He starts by saying the vectors $PQ$ and $QR$ have the same length and are perpendicular. You are right in your comment. He should have written $|QP|=|QR|$ (and $QP\perp QR$ to avoid confusion, in my opinion).

---

For your update, I'm not sure where he got that... You could do the following however:
From

$a-b =i(c-b)$, substitute $a=-1+4i$ and $c=1-2i$:
$$
(-1+4i)-b =i( (1-2i)-b)
$$
This gives:
$$
-1+4i-b= i+2-bi \iff -b+bi = i+2+1-4i\iff b(i-1)=3-3i.
$$

Comment: It looks like from the author's perspective, "PQ" and "QR" aren't vectors, they're line segments. That's why the || notation was omitted.

Answer (score 2):

From $$a-b=i(c-b)$$ you get $$a-b=ic-ib,\quad ib-b=ic-a,\quad (i-1)b=ic-a$$ Is there another part that you don't see?